# Select by for a two-dimensional hash

Tags: ruby

I have this hash

```
- "title" : "The Today Show",
- "category; "Show",
- "channel-name": "CNBC",
- "scheduling" => 
       { "start" : "7am", "stop" : "9am"},
       { "start" : "10am", "stop" : "11am"},
       { "start" : "11am", "stop": "12am"}
- "title" : "How I met your mother",
- "category; "Show",
- "channel-name": "CBS",
- "scheduling" => 
       { "start" : "7pm", "stop" : "9pm"},
       { "start" : "10pm", "stop" : "12pm"},
       { "start" : "11am", "stop": "12am"}
```

I need to "select" only programs which have at least one schedule beetween "7pm"-"9pm"

I tried this, but it isn't working

```
programs.select_by{|p| 
      p.scheduling.each{|ps|
         ps.start <= "7pm" && ps.stop <= "9pm"
   }
}
```

PS: I used a **pseudo-code** for the date-comparison just to make this code more readable :)

Comment: Did you mean `ps.start >= "7pm"`?

Comment: There might be an issue with your logic. What output are you expecting? What output do you get instead?

Comment: That isn't a valid hash definition, nor is it YAML. Where'd you get it, and what did you do with the real hash definition?

Comment: Yes, I have just type for this post

Comment: Use 24-hour time format so you can compare hours of day regardless of meridian.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
programs.select do |p| 
  p.scheduling.any? do |ps|
    ps.start >= "7pm" && ps.stop <= "9pm"
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this doesn't works in some cases (ie: `ps.start >= "5am" && ps.stop <= "2pm"` if `ps.stop == "8am"`). I suppose OP should use 24hours time format instead.

Comment: @ByScripts The OP said this was pseudo code so I guess he is using time objects in the real code

Comment: Oops. Didn't see its "PS:". Sorry.